In an Azure Data Factory "Copy" activity, how do you add a nested column to an XML source data set?
I need
In Azure Data Factory, I have a "Copy data" activity that uses an XML source data set. The structure of the XML is
<root>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
    </record>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
    </record>
    ...
</root>

How can I add a column3 as a child of the <record> nodes? The result would look like this:
<root>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
        <column3>...</column3>
    </record>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
        <column3>...</column3>
    </record>
    ...
</root>

I tried
I am trying to do this in the "Source" tab of the "Copy data" activity, which gives the option to add an "Additional column". I've tried syntax like the following for the name of the additional column:

$['root']['record']['column3']
/root/record/column3
root/record/column3
...other variations


Everything I've tried does add a "column" to the XML, but it adds it as a sibling to the root node (I see this by previewing the data set) and takes the entire syntax as a literal name, like this:
<root>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
    </record>
    <record>
        <column1>...</column1>
        <column2>...</column2>
    </record>
    ...
</root>
<$['root']['record']['column3']>
...
</$['root']['record']['column3']>

I need the new column to be a child of the record nodes. I've not found anything about this on the internet. Thanks!

Your XML main tag is root which is the name of the DataSet.  You have one DataTable which is called Record.  And the table Record has columns 1 & 2.  You are adding a new DataTable instead of adding a new column.

I created additional column as shown below:

Added sink dataset to the copy activity and imported the schema using Import schemas option under mapping section. I faced the same issue while creating an additional column, it added to root node as shown below:

To add column3 to the record node, you can follow the procedure below:
Go to the pipeline JSON, and under the mapping section, add "$['root']['record']['column3']" for column3, as shown below:

Then, you will be able to achieve your requirement, as shown below:


The source path you show indicates that the column3 is a child of the record nodes, which is what I want do do. But how do I get the additional column to be added to the record nodes? What is the syntax on the "Source" tab for the additional column name? Everything I've tried so far just adds a node as a sibling of the root node. If I could get the column added as a child of record, then the mapping you show should work.

I just created the column 3 as you created after adding sink imported the mapping and added $['root']['record']['column3'] as mentioned above

Thank you for your responses. If you still have it, would you be able to show a screenshot of the "Additional columns" "Name" field that you created on the "Source" tab?

@neizan I updated my answer please check it once.

@NaveenSharma I upvoted, because the information provided is useful and relevant. However, it does not answer the question, because it does not create a column as a child of a node--it creates it as a sibling of the root, which is the problem I'm trying to solve. That is why I've not accepted. I very much appreciate Bhavani's efforts, however.
